# What is "sperion"?

Tags: file, unix, macos, root, invisible-files

I'm cleaning up my boot drive & have come across a unix executable file located @ /private/tmp/sperion about which I can't seem to find any information at all. What is "sperion"?

This may be an unrelated question/problem but that private folder sperion is in [image: /private/tmp/sperion]is visible & I am consistently told that I do not have permission to chflags it hidden even with myself listed as having full permissions over the folder and the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a part of the software licensing service,  [Nalperion](http://www.nalpeiron.com)

Unless you know what app you have that  uses it for licensing, then maybe the simplest way to find out would be to kill the Nalperion service from Activity Monitor & wait til one app complains.

Comment: Thank you! I had Color Efex Pro 4 installed, which uses Nalperion for "security". I removed all of it.